# What is the highest hex value in programming?

Tags: hex

So when looking at integers, the highest value is 2^31-1 and min is -2^31. I was wondering what it would be for hex? Is that a realistic question or am I asking nonsense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly:  the largest value for a 31 bit integer is 2147483647.  This number in hex is 0x7FFFFFFF, but the values are identical.

Since integers are usually stored in memory as signed integers in fields 32 bits long, this generally sets the maximum to be 214748347 regardless of how the number is stored, although many programming languages support long integer types that are 64 bits long.  There is also a scientific notation representation that can represent larger numbers, but I think that it is "cheating" in regards to actually storing an integer.